# Find all possible teams in R

Tags: r, combinatorics, combn

Feels like this should be straightforward but I have been through stack overflow and `combn` help, and cannot see solution.

The below players need to be in teams of 3 versus 2. I need to find all possible combinations of teams. For example two possible teams are "Ross", "Bobby" and "Casper" in one team, and "Max" and "Jake" in the other team. How can I code this?

```
players <- c("Ross", "Bobby", "Max", "Casper", "Jake")
```

Comment: FYI, many developers *strongly* discourage the use of left-to-right assignment in scripts. It makes the assignment action non-obvious, which drastically reduces clarity about the data flow (which variables exist, and what is their current value?) and thus makes code harder to read, debug and modify.

Comment: I use pipes in my code and put assignment on right so everything flows from top to bottom

Comment: Please have a look at the second-to-last paragraph of [this comment](https://win-vector.com/2016/12/12/the-case-for-using-in-r/#comment-875) explaining why this is a bad idea for code maintainability.

Answer (score 18):

I think the key step is to randomly choose 3 (or 2) out of 5 players to generate the first team, and the remaining are naturally assigned to the second team.

Probably you can try it like this

```
combn(players,
  3, 
  function(x) list(team1 = x, team2 = players[!players %in% x]),
  simplify = FALSE
)
```

or if you don't mind the time efficiency, you can use `setdiff` instead

```
combn(players,
    3,
    function(x) list(team1 = x, team2 = setdiff(players, x)),
    simplify = FALSE
  )
```

and either of which gives

```
[[1]]
[[1]]$team1
[1] "Ross"  "Bobby" "Max"

[[1]]$team2
[1] "Casper" "Jake"


[[2]]
[[2]]$team1
[1] "Ross"   "Bobby"  "Casper"

[[2]]$team2
[1] "Max"  "Jake"


[[3]]
[[3]]$team1
[1] "Ross"  "Bobby" "Jake"

[[3]]$team2
[1] "Max"    "Casper"


[[4]]
[[4]]$team1
[1] "Ross"   "Max"    "Casper"

[[4]]$team2
[1] "Bobby" "Jake"


[[5]]
[[5]]$team1
[1] "Ross" "Max"  "Jake"

[[5]]$team2
[1] "Bobby"  "Casper"


[[6]]
[[6]]$team1
[1] "Ross"   "Casper" "Jake"

[[6]]$team2
[1] "Bobby" "Max"


[[7]]
[[7]]$team1
[1] "Bobby"  "Max"    "Casper"

[[7]]$team2
[1] "Ross" "Jake"


[[8]]
[[8]]$team1
[1] "Bobby" "Max"   "Jake"

[[8]]$team2
[1] "Ross"   "Casper"


[[9]]
[[9]]$team1
[1] "Bobby"  "Casper" "Jake"

[[9]]$team2
[1] "Ross" "Max"


[[10]]
[[10]]$team1
[1] "Max"    "Casper" "Jake"

[[10]]$team2
[1] "Ross"  "Bobby"
```

---

## Benchmarking

```
players <- c("Ross", "Bobby", "Max", "Casper", "Jake")

microbenchmark(
  f1 = combn(players,
    3,
    function(x) list(team1 = x, team2 = players[!players %in% x]),
    simplify = FALSE
  ),
  f2 = combn(players,
    3,
    function(x) list(team1 = x, team2 = setdiff(players, x)),
    simplify = FALSE
  )
)
```

and we will see

```
Unit: microseconds
 expr    min      lq      mean   median       uq      max neval
   f1 26.200 28.0510  51.55586  29.4515  32.5015 1935.301   100
   f2 97.301 99.8505 119.44610 103.6010 111.1510 1162.501   100
```

Comment: `players[!players %in% x])` can be simplified to `setdiff(players, x)`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph yes, I was thinking of `setdiff` but it would be slow for larger sizes of `players` or `x`, so I use `%in%` instead

Comment: Hmm, I don't think it should be slower. Am I wrong?

Comment: @KonradRudolph I added a benchmark

Comment: Okay, I did not expect that. Thanks for adding the benchmark. I have to think about why this is happening.

Comment: @KonradRudolph, if you look at `setdiff`, it is doing a lot more than `%in%`. In the console, we see `setdiff` ends up doing `u[!duplicated(unclass(u)) & (match(u, v, 0L) == 0L)]` whereas `%in%` simply calls `match(x, table, nomatch = 0L) > 0L`.

Comment: @JosephWood Yes, I saw that as well. It's definitely not an optimal implementation (`match` and `duplicated` will end up doing largely redundant work, and a better implementation would do this work only once).

Answer (score 7):

There is a function in `RcppAlgos` (I am the author) called `comboGroups` built precisely for this task. As of version `2.8.0`, we can now handle groups of varying sizes.

```r
library(RcppAlgos)
packageVersion("RcppAlgos")
#> [1] '2.8.0'
```

We specify the size of each team using the `grpSizes` parameter:

```r
players <- c("Ross", "Bobby", "Max", "Casper", "Jake")
comboGroups(players, grpSizes = c(2, 3))
#>       Grp1     Grp1     Grp2    Grp2     Grp2    
#>  [1,] "Ross"   "Bobby"  "Max"   "Casper" "Jake"  
#>  [2,] "Ross"   "Max"    "Bobby" "Casper" "Jake"  
#>  [3,] "Ross"   "Casper" "Bobby" "Max"    "Jake"  
#>  [4,] "Ross"   "Jake"   "Bobby" "Max"    "Casper"
#>  [5,] "Bobby"  "Max"    "Ross"  "Casper" "Jake"  
#>  [6,] "Bobby"  "Casper" "Ross"  "Max"    "Jake"  
#>  [7,] "Bobby"  "Jake"   "Ross"  "Max"    "Casper"
#>  [8,] "Max"    "Casper" "Ross"  "Bobby"  "Jake"  
#>  [9,] "Max"    "Jake"   "Ross"  "Bobby"  "Casper"
#> [10,] "Casper" "Jake"   "Ross"  "Bobby"  "Max"
```

It is very efficient and quite flexible. Let’s test on a larger set of players.

```r
library(microbenchmark)
more_players <- c(players, "Kai", "Eliana", "Jayden", "Luca",
                  "Rowan", "Nova", "Amara", "Finn", "Zion", "Mia")

microbenchmark(
    f1 = combn(more_players,
               7,
               function(x) list(team1 = x, team2 = more_players[!more_players %in% x]),
               simplify = FALSE
    ),
    f2 = combn(more_players,
               7,
               function(x) list(team1 = x, team2 = setdiff(more_players, x)),
               simplify = FALSE
    ),
    f3_rcpp = comboGeneral(
        v = more_players,
        m = 7,
        repetition = FALSE,
        FUN = function(x) list(team1 = x, team2 = more_players[!more_players %in% x])
    ),
    f4 = comboGroups(more_players, grpSizes = c(7, 8)),
    unit = "relative"
)
#> Unit: relative
#>     expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq       max neval  cld
#>       f1 16.22184 19.03265 23.68141 20.78979 26.59770  92.08256   100 a   
#>       f2 41.34947 45.55672 57.30847 54.70320 59.88822 123.09864   100  b  
#>  f3_rcpp 11.83424 14.48575 17.65936 16.24856 21.43574  36.27697   100   c 
#>       f4  1.00000  1.00000  1.00000  1.00000  1.00000   1.00000   100    d
```

### More than 2 Groups

What about more exotic groupings? With most other approaches, efficiency and code maintenance will be an issue.

Say for example, given `more_players` (15 total players) what if we wanted to find all possible groupings with 2 teams of size 3, one team of size 4, and one team of size 5?

With `comboGroups`, it is no problem:

```r
system.time(t <- comboGroups(more_players, grpSizes = c(3, 3, 4, 5)))
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>   0.508   0.040   0.548 

head(t, n = 2)
#>      Grp1   Grp1    Grp1  Grp2     Grp2   Grp2  Grp3     Grp3     Grp3   Grp3   
#> [1,] "Ross" "Bobby" "Max" "Casper" "Jake" "Kai" "Eliana" "Jayden" "Luca" "Rowan"
#> [2,] "Ross" "Bobby" "Max" "Casper" "Jake" "Kai" "Eliana" "Jayden" "Luca" "Nova" 
#>      Grp4    Grp4    Grp4   Grp4   Grp4 
#> [1,] "Nova"  "Amara" "Finn" "Zion" "Mia"
#> [2,] "Rowan" "Amara" "Finn" "Zion" "Mia"

tail(t, n = 2)
#>            Grp1    Grp1   Grp1  Grp2   Grp2    Grp2   Grp3   Grp3     Grp3    
#> [6306299,] "Rowan" "Zion" "Mia" "Nova" "Amara" "Finn" "Jake" "Eliana" "Jayden"
#> [6306300,] "Rowan" "Zion" "Mia" "Nova" "Amara" "Finn" "Kai"  "Eliana" "Jayden"
#>            Grp3   Grp4   Grp4    Grp4  Grp4     Grp4  
#> [6306299,] "Luca" "Ross" "Bobby" "Max" "Casper" "Kai" 
#> [6306300,] "Luca" "Ross" "Bobby" "Max" "Casper" "Jake"
```

If you just need a sample of possible teams, try `comboGroupsSample`:

```r
comboGroupsSample(
    more_players, grpSizes = c(3, 3, 4, 5), n = 2,
    seed = 42, namedSample = TRUE
)
#>         Grp1    Grp1     Grp1   Grp2    Grp2    Grp2   Grp3   Grp3     Grp3    
#> 3207141 "Bobby" "Jake"   "Mia"  "Luca"  "Amara" "Zion" "Max"  "Casper" "Eliana"
#> 4248729 "Max"   "Casper" "Nova" "Rowan" "Amara" "Finn" "Ross" "Bobby"  "Kai"   
#>         Grp3    Grp4   Grp4     Grp4     Grp4   Grp4  
#> 3207141 "Rowan" "Ross" "Kai"    "Jayden" "Nova" "Finn"
#> 4248729 "Luca"  "Jake" "Eliana" "Jayden" "Zion" "Mia"
```

Comment: `RcppAlgos` keeps being better. Nice work!

Answer (score 6):

Just to build off @ThomasIsCoding great answer. Further speed could be gained by using the great RcppAlgos library and the `comboGeneral` function:

```
players <- c("Ross", "Bobby", "Max", "Casper", "Jake")

microbenchmark(
  f1 = combn(players,
             3,
             function(x) list(team1 = x, team2 = players[!players %in% x]),
             simplify = FALSE
  ),
  f2 = combn(players,
             3,
             function(x) list(team1 = x, team2 = setdiff(players, x)),
             simplify = FALSE
  ),
  f3_rcpp = RcppAlgos::comboGeneral(
    v = players,
    m = 3,
    repetition = FALSE,
    FUN = function(x) list(team1 = x, team2 = players[!players %in% x])
  )
)
```

**BENCHMARK**

```
Unit: microseconds
    expr   min     lq    mean median     uq    max neval
      f1  34.3  37.95  63.693  39.00  41.45 2016.7   100
      f2 143.5 152.40 184.351 155.30 158.95 1961.7   100
 f3_rcpp  29.3  32.40  61.820  33.95  42.40 2205.0   100
```